# Modifying JobDataMap in Quartz.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, quartz.net

I am creating a Quartz.NET application in C#, and creating a bunch of administration webpages (C#/ASP.NET) so users can easily create jobs, set datamap fields and edit datamap fields.

I'm having some trouble editting jobs data maps though - any changes I make aren't saved at all. Is there anything I need to call after modifying the jobs data map?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone that has trouble too, this is easily solved by calling the AddJob method of the schedule variable

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Quartz.Net version 1+ you must implement `Quartz.IStatefulJob` interface for your jobs.

```
public class MyJob : Quartz.IStatefulJob
{
    //...
}
```

This interface is obsolete in Quartz.Net 2+ so you have to add `[Quartz.PersistJobDataAfterExecutionAttribute()]` to your job class. Also you may need to add `[Quartz.DisallowConcurrentExecutionAttribute()]` to your job class.

```
[Quartz.PersistJobDataAfterExecutionAttribute()]
[Quartz.DisallowConcurrentExecutionAttribute()]
public class MyJob : Quartz.IJob
{
    //...
}
```